# How to copy files from AWS S3 to local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to copy the files which are newly updated in S3 bucket using AWS CLI to local machine?

Can we compare the logs and do the copy?

Answer (score 8):

You can use either the `aws s3 cp` command, or if you want to only synchronise new files you can use the `aws s3 sync` command.

The syntax is below

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket . --recursive
```

The documentations are available below:

- [aws s3 cp](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)
- [aws s3 sync](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Comment: But these commands will download the files every time. I want to copy the new files every 10 mins. This will consume a lot of bandwidth. Can I use Read-S3Object?

Comment: aws s3 sync will only synchronise new file changes

Comment: [s3 copy examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html#using-s3-commands-managing-objects-copy)        [s3 sync examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html#using-s3-commands-managing-objects-sync)